# how to use Sense (or any other suggested tool) to help beginners with ELK

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin, sense, xpack

I have tried few approaches:

1)

-I downloaded Sense from https://github.com/bleskes/sense, unzipped and pasted it in kibana-5.3.0-amd64/usr/share/kibana/plugins

-I started kibana and then I got "[warning] Plugin "Sense" was disabled because it expected Kibana version "2.0.0-snapshot", and found "5.3.0"

```
demetrio@nodejs ~/Servers/DBs/elasticsearch-5.3.0/bin $ cd /home/demetrio/Servers/DBs/kibana-5.3.0-amd64/usr/share/kibana/bin
demetrio@nodejs ~/Servers/DBs/kibana-5.3.0-amd64/usr/share/kibana/bin $ ./kibana
undefined accessed the autoload lists which are no longer available via the Plugin API.Use the `ui/autoload/*` modules instead.
undefined accessed the autoload lists which are no longer available via the Plugin API.Use the `ui/autoload/*` modules instead.
  log   [20:25:48.403] [warning] Plugin "Sense" was disabled because it expected Kibana version "2.0.0-snapshot", and found "5.3.0".
  log   [20:25:49.123] [info][status][plugin:kibana@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [20:25:49.279] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [20:25:49.326] [info][status][plugin:console@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [20:25:49.842] [info][status][plugin:timelion@5.3.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [20:25:49.873] [info][listening] Server running at http://localhost:5601
  log   [20:25:49.875] [info][status][ui settings] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Elasticsearch plugin is yellow
  log   [20:25:50.041] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.3.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Kibana index ready
  log   [20:25:50.043] [info][status][ui settings] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
```

2)

I tried installed, as suggested in https://github.com/bleskes/sense by following

```
demetrio@nodejs ~/Servers/DBs/kibana-5.3.0-amd64/usr/share/kibana/bin $ ./kibana plugin --install elastic/sense

 ERROR  unknown command plugin
```

3)

I tried to install

```
demetrio@nodejs ~/Servers/DBs/kibana-5.3.0-amd64/usr/share/kibana/bin $ ./kibana-plugin install elastic/sense
Attempting to transfer from elastic/sense
Attempting to transfer from https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugins/elastic/sense/elastic/sense-5.3.0.zip
Error: Client request error: connect ETIMEDOUT 107.21.249.70:443
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Client request error: connect ETIMEDOUT 107.21.249.70:443"
```

P.S. I checked my Debian proxy configuration and it is correct. Should I add my proxy configs in some specific Kibana file?

4)

I tried installed it from Google Chrome Store but it seems that such plugin is no mode maintained after version 2 and ELK is currently in 5.3

5)

I installed X-Pack (https://www.elastic.co/downloads/x-pack) but, as far as I noted until now, the only significant different was an user creation for each of ELK. I was locking for some thing like described here https://github.com/bleskes/sense

- Handy API suggestions
- Format validation
- Scope collapsing
- Auto formatting
- Submit multiple requests at once
- Copy and Paste cURL commands

To sum up, I am locking for some tool that could make a bit easier for a dummy like to make queries and interact with ELK. I saw few pictures that drove to conclusion that Sense is a good tool for that but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool are off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. You may be able to ask this on [softwarerecs.se] instead, but make sure you visit their help pages and review the guidelines first; they're pretty strict about the questions they allow there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sense is now included in Kibana. Start Kibana (default port 5601) and look at DevTools. X-Pack is actually an expansion for monitoring, alerting and security purposes. [kibana console doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/console-kibana.html)

So for you it would be best to start exploring elasticsearch by using kibana devtools.

Comment: the link "kibana console doc" moved to no where.